# Touchable info (i) button on top of Scroll View

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Is there better (framework built in) way to add small "touchable" round info button (i) on top of scroll view? Theoretically I think there should be container view for button(UIControl or UIImageView with png?) and scroll view.

Comment: What is wrong with the standard info button?

Comment: Nothing, but how would I place it on top of scroll view, without losing scrolling functionality? Any sample would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your information button float above the scroll view by adding it to the scroll view's superview, then ordering the views such that the information button resides on top of the scroll view.  You'll retain scrolling capability, while still catching button touches.